# Setting height of QMenu items

Tags: qt, menu, qmenu

Is it possible to style a `QMenu:item` to set a custom height?

I need it for a popup menu,  by what I've been seeing it seems it's not possible but maybe someone knows for sure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you tried to use `QSS`? This works fine for me:

```
QMenu::item {
    height: 42px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

You can use `pMenu->setStyleSheet("QMenu::item { height: 42px; margin: 0px; }");`.

**Note:** Make sure you use `::` and not `:` to reference the item.

Comment: Yes I've tried that (setting programmatically) but with no effect althought other attributes -colors- are reflected well. I've tried under Windows and Android with the same non-result. I've also copy/pasted verbatim your code with no other attribs, (I know I make many typos :-) but with no result either.